# Mongoid 'where' query returning Mongoid::Criteria instead of result (undefined method for #<Mongoid::Criteria)

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, criteria

I am querying a model in my controller with the following code:

```
@user_forecast = UserForecast.where(forecast_id: user_forecast_params[:forecast_id] , project_role_id: user_forecast_params[:project_role_id])
```

The model is defined correctly, the params are present. However, instead of returning an instance of UserForecast, it returns an instance of Mongoid::Criteria.

This line

```
logger.debug @user_forecast.id
```

results in the following error:
`

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x00000004caa108>):
```

I have no clue what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what Mongoid's `where` does: it builds a query represented as a `Mongoid::Criteria` object. ActiveRecord does the same thing and the solutions are the same:

1. Use `first`/`last`/... to grab just one result from the query:

   ```
   @user_forecast = UserForecast.where(...).first
   ```
2. Better, use `find_by` to find exactly one if you're expecting there to be only one:

   ```
   @user_forecast = UserForecast.find_by(
     forecast_id:     user_forecast_params[:forecast_id],
     project_role_id: user_forecast_params[:project_role_id]
   )
   @user_forecast = UserForecast.find_by(
     user_forecast_params.slice(:forcecast_id, :project_role_id)
   )
   ```